# Getting stimulus-components' stimulus-carousel to fire with importmaps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, import-maps

Based on section 2 of the [installation documentation for stimulus-components](https://www.stimulus-components.com/docs/installation/), a test was conducted to render [the usage case](https://www.stimulus-components.com/docs/stimulus-carousel/) given for this controller

```
<div data-controller="carousel" class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

which unfortunately rendered a banal block of divs
[image: block 'o divs]

Pinning the controller led to the following installations:

```
./bin/importmap pin stimulus-carousel
Pinning "stimulus-carousel" to https://ga.jspm.io/npm:stimulus-carousel@5.0.1/dist/stimulus-carousel.mjs
Pinning "@hotwired/stimulus" to https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@hotwired/stimulus@3.2.1/dist/stimulus.js
Pinning "dom7" to https://ga.jspm.io/npm:dom7@4.0.6/dom7.esm.js
Pinning "ssr-window" to https://ga.jspm.io/npm:ssr-window@4.0.2/ssr-window.esm.js
Pinning "swiper/bundle" to https://ga.jspm.io/npm:swiper@8.4.7/swiper-bundle.esm.js
```

the application.js was amended with `import "swiper/css/bundle"` at the bottom of file, as suggested in the "Before starting" section of the second link.
*the browser console does complain that 'Uncaught TypeError: The specifier “swiper/css/bundle” was a bare specifier, but was not remapped to anything. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”.'  but that is an expected error*

A stimulus_carousel.js  controller was created with:

```
import Carousel from 'stimulus-carousel'
window.Stimulus = Application.start()
Stimulus.register('carousel', Carousel)
```

What is missing/wrong in this setup to get the controller to layout (and execute) properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Controller registration doesn't change from controller to controller, it's the same thing for all of them:

```js
// app/javascript/controllers/index.js
// ...
import Carousel from "stimulus-carousel";
application.register("carousel", Carousel);
```

You don't have "swiper/css/bundle" in your import-maps to import it, and you can't import *css* files with import-maps anyway. Get styles from a cdn.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@9/swiper-bundle.min.css" />

<%= tag.div class: "swiper", data: {
  controller: "carousel",
  carousel_options_value: {
    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination"
    },
    navigation: {
      nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
      prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
    },
    effect: "coverflow"
  }
} do %>
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
<% end %>

<style type="text/css" media="screen">.swiper-slide { height: 20rem; background-color: pink; display: grid; place-items: center; }</style>
```

Seems like more work and no benefit.

---

Compared to [this](https://swiperjs.com/element) set up, which took like a minute:

```bash
bin/importmap pin swiper/element/bundle
```

```js
// app/javascript/application.js
import { register } from "swiper/element/bundle";
register();
```

```html
<swiper-container navigation="true" pagination="true" scrollbar="true" effect="coverflow">
  <swiper-slide>
    <div class="h-64 grid place-items-center bg-stone-50">Slide 1</div>
  </swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide>
    <div class="h-64 grid place-items-center bg-stone-50">Slide 2</div>
  </swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide>
    <div class="h-64 grid place-items-center bg-stone-50">Slide 3</div>
  </swiper-slide>
</swiper-container>
```

Comment: A very useful response, as it first focuses on efficiency, but also helps highlight how the whole 'convention' paradigm with importmaps is not that firmly established.